# Teapot mark in small seal characters?

Tags: meaning

I was given a wonderful teapot, but cannot understand the mark at its bottom. Is it small seal script? I think the character on the top right should be 局, but what about the others? Thank you for your help[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure it is 宜興？壼  (There is no 局)

Comment: Thanks Tang Ho! Yes, I also think they are right! Now I have to decipher them! Thank you so much!

Comment: My guess is 宜興老壼
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfkRG.png

Comment: And the meaning then should be “old Yixing Teapot”, at least according to Pleco App! Thank you again Tang Ho!

Comment: Search 宜興老壼 and found [仿古](https://world.taobao.com/item/637697465530.htm?spm=a21wu.12321156-tw.recommend-tpp.5) -- modeled after an antique

Comment: Yes, it should be a copy of an old teapot…

Answer (score 1):

I am sure it is 宜興石壺 (Yixing stone pot)

石

[image]

Comment: seems to be the same to me.